# how to get a ranking from a sqlite table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to know how to get a ranking from a sqlite table.

```
Date        |R1 |R2 |R3   
03/01/2020  |8  |9  |6
02/01/2020  |12 |8  |6
01/01/2020  |7  |12 |6
```

I don't know if there isn't a query that would generate a result like

Result:

```
7
12
8
9
6
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you derive those numbers from that table? What's the logic?

Comment: Hello, 
These figures come from a ranking of horse races. From the daily ranking, I would like to generate a ranking over these 3 days: assuming that in line 1 horse 8 finished ahead of 9 and 6 and that if we take the result of line 2 horse 12 finished ahead of 8 and 6. so between these two results we can define  that horse 12 is better than horse 8 
so the ranking after these two races is 
12- 8 - 9 - 6
etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union all` :

```
select distinct r
from (select r1 as r, date, 1 as id
      from t union all
      select r2, date, 2
      from t union all
      select r3, date, 3
      from t
     ) t
order by id, date;
```

Comment: Thanks a lots, Perfect I have added a distinct select r distinct to have a list without duplicate values